# CnosDB show datanodes did not retrieve any data

Tags: cnosdb

```
oceanic_station ❯ show datanodes;
+---------+------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+-------------------+
| NODE_ID | HOST | ATTRIBUTE | STATUS | DISK_FREE | DISK_TOTAL | LAST_UPDATED_TIME |
+---------+------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+-------------------+
+---------+------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+-------------------+
Query took 0.131 seconds.
```

I executed 'show datanodes' under the cnosdb-cli in a Unix environment, but it did not retrieve any data, and there was no error thrown by the system. I intended to use this data to calculate disk occupancy. Has anyone encountered this issue before?